# Has anyone heard of a "Coin mode"?

Tags: system-error

Someone asked me how to get out of "Coin mode" the other day. The user in question may have misunderstood a prompt or been confused as I was unable to reproduce the specific error. However there definitely were errors. I have never heard of it, and would like more information on it if it exists. Connecting with a wifi network seems to have resolve the issues, however if that was the issue, it should have corrected itself using the data connection via mobile without intervention. It is my guess that "coin mode" may have been an error given by an application rather than the OS?

It had stopped working as normal after several months of standard behavior. Supposedly an icon of the Android-guy came up and said device was in "coin mode" or something similar.

The device was a Samsung Nexus phone running 4.2.1 which must have been pushed onto it as the user would not have modified her own phone herself. The time became messed up, and the last system update was listed as in the year 1999. The tool-bar on the top was also messed up. The device had several other glitches, including the backgrounds not properly updating when in applications such as Google play.

Comment: Not heard of such a thing, no. I assume you did a web search for it? Did they perhaps mean "kiosk mode"?

Comment: I'd rather say **offline** mode (or "airplane mode"), as a network (WiFi) connection solved the issue. Most likely one app needed network access and complained not being able to "work in offline mode". Though the last paragraph points to a bigger problem, which *might* need a factory-reset to be cured (more information needed to confirm that).

Comment: Ooops: [Help! Stuck in Coin Mode - xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=21645630) => ODIN mode *LOL* Yeah, that also explain the "Andy @ Work". Though people already thought about a Google-Wallet-"insert a coin"-error #D // BTW: 11.100 results for a [Google search on 'android "coin mode"'](http://www.google.com/search?q=android+"coin+mode") :-O